# Passing cookies between requests in Postman runner

Tags: cookies, postman

I'm writing a Postman collection to be executed in Postman Runner, which requires that cookies from a first request be used in subsequent requests.

In curl, you can achieve this like so

```
curl -d "username=x&password=y" -c logincookie.txt https://service.com/login
curl -b logincookie.txt https://service.com/x/profile
```

I can't seem to do this in Postman.

[As documented](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox), in my test for the first request I save the cookie as an environment variable

```
var login_cookie = postman.getResponseCookie("LOGIN");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("login_cookie", login_cookie);
```

and then, [as described in this blog post](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests), I add the following header to the subsequent request,

```
Cookie: {{login_cookie}}
```

but the server responds to this request as if the cookie was not provided.

How can I pass the cookie from the first response to the second request?

I'm using the Postman for Mac 4.10.7 and have enabled the interceptor with its default settings, although I don't know how to validate that this actually works!

Comment: I am very interested in achieving the same thing. Seems there is no way to do this.

Comment: It's been a year since this question was asked, so maybe this wasn't the case then, but today cookies are persisted across requests in the collection. You can view/confirm this by clicking on the "Cookies" label located just under the Send and Save buttons on the right.